# Problem representing data using geom point in R's ggplot 2. Is it possible to change the margins of a plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis

I have developed the following code to represent data of the iris libary

```
  df<-iris
    ggplot(df, aes(x= Sepal.Length, y= Sepal.Width, colour=Species, label=Species))+
  geom_point() +geom_text(hjust=0, vjust=0)+ theme(legend.position = "none")
```

However, as can be seen, some of the rightmost names are clipped out of the figure. I was wondering if there is a way for me to force the end of the right axis to end at 8.5?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X limits can be set explicitly with `scale_x_continuous` e.g. adding

```
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(NA, 8.5))
```

to your code. Setting the lower limit as `NA` leaves it unchanged from the default.